Displaying geolocation jumps out of div
The div is broken, the <p>'s are written outside of it.
I suspect it's a response time problem, but I'm not able to fix it.
If I remove the jQuery button effect and div all together, I'm able to have the location displayed just fine.
I'd prefer to have the script in the header, but I any solution is welcome.
$(document).ready(function() {
  var banner = $("#banner-message");
  var button = $("button");

  // handle click and add class
  button.on("click", () => {
    banner.toggleClass("alt");
  });
});


// Beregn afstand mellem 2 punkter
function distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = (lat2 - lat1).toRad(); // Javascript functions in radians
  var dLon = (lon2 - lon1).toRad();
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

/** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}

window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
  console.log(pos);
  console.log(
    distance(pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude, 9.318893232332728, 56.53058705206541)
  );
});

// Check if the browser supports geolocation 
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {

  // Get the user's current position 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) {
      let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      let accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;


      document.body.innerHTML += "<div id=\"banner-message\">";
      document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Geolocation test</p>";


      document.body.innerHTML +=
        "<p>Latitude: " + latitude + "</p>";
      document.body.innerHTML +=
        "<p>Longitude: " + longitude + "</p>";
      document.body.innerHTML +=
        "<p>Accuracy indenfor: " + accuracy + " meter</p>";


      const Afstand = distance(longitude, latitude, 9.418893232332728, 56.93058705206541);

      document.body.innerHTML +=
        "<p>Afstand: " + Math.round(Afstand * 1000) + " meter</p>";


      document.body.innerHTML += "<button>Change coloring</button>";
      document.body.innerHTML += "</div>";


      //SLEEP er her fordi der ikke er en WAIT funktion i Javascript !
      function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }
      //Check om accuracy er under 200 meter - ellers refresh siden efter 7 sekunder.
      /*
      if (Math.round(Afstand*1000) > 200) {
        sleep(7000).then(() => {
        location.reload();
      });   
      }
      */
    },

    function(error) {
      console.error("Error getting location: " + error.message);
    }
  );
} else {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by your browser");
}

body {
  background: #FFE0AF;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #F7F7F0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #BAF1BE;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #FFBFBF;
  color: #000;
}

Working example

Let's start with a real MRE, not the whole code


function f(){
    document.body.innerHTML = '<div>';
    document.body.innerHTML += '<span>Hello</span>';
    document.body.innerHTML += '</div>';
}
div {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
body {
     background-color: red;
}
<body>
<button onclick='f()'>GO</button>



The CSS part is to see whether span is in div or not: if it is, background should be green. If hello is on red background, then it is not in div.
Indeed, it is not.
To understand why so, let's consider an even simpler f
function f(){
    document.body.innerHTML='<div>Unclosed';
}

What you see then: unclosed on green background. And if you inspect the dom, you'll see a closed <div>Unclosed</div>.
Because as soon as you add <div> to  innerHTML, what it does is create a <div></div>. With an implicit end.
Then when you add <span>Hello</span> to that, it add it after the div.
Then adding a single </div> has no effect.
You cannot have partial HTML in innerHTML. Engine will complete it for you.
Yet another way to see it


function f(){
     let div=document.getElementById('outer');
     let pre=document.getElementById('code');
     pre.textContent = '----\nInit\n' + div.innerHTML+'\n\n';
     div.innerHTML = '<div>';
     pre.textContent += '----\nAfter div\n'+div.innerHTML+'\n\n';
     div.innerHTML += '<b>Hello</b>';
     pre.textContent += '----\nAfter hello\n'+div.innerHTML+'\n\n';
     div.innerHTML += '</div>';
     pre.textContent += '----\nAfter /div\n'+div.innerHTML+'\n\n';
}
#outer {
    background-color: red;
}
#outer div {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

pre {
    background-color: yellow;
}
<button onclick='f()'>GO</button>
<div id=outer></div>
<pre id=code></pre>



This time, I added a (yellow) pre that displays div#outer content code (I change innerHTML of div#outer rather than body to be able to keep my pre.
You can see that, as I said, as soon as you add <div>, code becomes <div></div>. And therefore <b>Hello</b> is outside that div (but of course inside #outer div, that represents what would be body in your case), and is on red background
So, you cannot increase innerHTML incrementally like this.
You must change innerHTML in one time.
I mean, for a subtree. Obviously, you can increase innerHTML incrementally to add more and more <div>Bla</div> if you want. But the point is innerHTML must always, at any moment, contain a valid html. You cannot have illegal HTML in it, even temporarilly. Or else, in best case scenario, engine will infer what is missing and add it for you. And if it can't guess, it will simply ignore the addition.
For example document.body.innerHTML='<di'; document.body.innerHTML+='v>Hello</div>'; displays just the text v>Hello. Because it ignores the <di part that makes no sense. Then find some text v>Hello. Then find a closing of a never opened div, that it also discard.
Solution
Well, imho, the best solution would be to use dom manipulation code rather than build html. But if you need/want to handle HTML like this, you should not do it incrementally, or at least (as said before) not in a way that have innerHTML being temporarilly an non-html, partial string.
If needed use another variable to accumulate what you want, and then put it in innerHTML
function f(){
    let s='<div>';
    s+='<span>Hello</span>';
    s+='</div>';
    document.body.innerHTML = s;
}

For example, correcting my last code


function f(){
     let div=document.getElementById('outer');
     let pre=document.getElementById('code');
     pre.textContent = '----\nInit\n' + div.innerHTML+'\n\n';
     let s  = '<div>';
     pre.textContent += '----\nAfter div\n'+div.innerHTML+'\n\n';
     s += '<b>Hello</b>';
     pre.textContent += '----\nAfter hello\n'+div.innerHTML+'\n\n';
     s += '</div>';
     pre.textContent += '----\nAfter /div\n'+div.innerHTML+'\n\n';
     div.innerHTML = s;
     pre.textContent += '----\nAfter innerHTML←s\n'+div.innerHTML+'\n\n';         
}
#outer {
    background-color: red;
}
#outer div {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

pre {
    background-color: yellow;
}
<button onclick='f()'>GO</button>
<div id=outer></div>
<pre id=code></pre>



This time, Hello is on green background, because it is inside the div. No implicit closing of that div ocurrend, before we added the Hello and the explicit </div> ourselves.

That is an amazing answer - thank you for taking your time to write that. I still don't understand DOM manipulation, but you provide an answer that I can use. Everything gets into the right div now. The button still doesn't change color, but I understand a lot more now..
